# How to upload files as certain user:nobody if apache is running as nobody:nobody?

Tags: wordpress, apache, permissions, centos

We have a shared hosting server, following is what is returned by `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`:

```
nobody   2665023  0.0  0.3 1969096 89628 ?       Sl   10:09   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
nobody   2665024  0.0  0.1 1968928 41304 ?       Sl   10:09   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
nobody   2665025  0.0  0.4 1969432 100008 ?      Sl   10:09   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
nobody   2665971  0.0  0.4 1969432 100880 ?      Sl   10:09   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
nobody   2665972  0.0  0.4 1969096 110268 ?      Sl   10:09   0:18 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
nobody   2665973  0.0  0.4 1969768 105648 ?      Sl   10:09   0:12 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

A client has a **wordpress** website with the user `myuser`.

When an image is uploaded, its owner is `nobody:nobody` , and cannot be directly accessed from the browser until I execute `chown -R myuser:nobody /uploads`.|

The problem here is that I cannot execute apache as `myuser:nobody` since there are other clients on this server (myuser1, myuser2...etc).

How can I possibly solve this?

(I only have general knowledge about permissions, so forgive my ignorance).

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "directly viewed"?

Comment: Cannot be accessed from the browser, I edited

Answer (score -1):

Brother you have to login as root to the vps server first. Then have to give ownership to each client user like this chown -R /home/client/wp-content/upload.
After that apply su as each client and put recursive permission on files 644 and 775 on directories.
find /home/client/wp-content/upload -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,go=rx {} ;
find /home/client/wp-content/upload -type f -exec chmod u=rw,go=r {} ;

Then you can able to upload images using wordpress media library. Each site also shows the images also.